# Are private methods as bad as public fields?

Tags: java, oop

Please excuse the provocative question title.  It's well known that you're never supposed to use public fields in a Java program (except in struct-like classes, which you're supposed to avoid anyway).  But people talk far less about the other side of the coin - private methods.

The way I see it is this: if you have private methods, then you are writing locally procedural code.  There is essentially no difference between a Java class with private fields and a few public methods which call a number of private methods, and a C module with global variables and some functions, some of which are `extern`ed elsewhere (apart from the fairly big difference that you can't instantiate a C module).  Given that a lot of the people who care most about good Java practice take the view that you should stay as far out of the procedural rut as possible, I'm surprised that there aren't more guidelines limiting the use of private methods.

Note that I don't want to suggest that anybody thinks that private methods should never be used (or that they're actually as bad as public fields).  But here are my questions, which I've tried to make as objective as possible:

- **Are there any standard Java guidelines limiting the use of private methods?**  (An example of a standard guideline is 'no public fields' - though you could argue that it's a matter of opinion, it's pretty much universally accepted to be good practice not to use public fields).
- How do I get round using private methods?  (For example, one can get round using public fields by declaring them private and using public get/set methods.  If I have a class with lots of private methods in it, I imagine that I ought to be creating a new class to hold them.  But if I do that, then I run the risk of writing a Java class that is never instantiated and behaves exactly like a C module.  **Are there any widely-used design patterns that can help me reduce the number of private methods in my classes?**)

Comment: Could the close voters please explain why you think this is primarily opinion based?

Comment: have you thought about, why private methods were used all over in jdk source codes, if they were bad?

Comment: Heck, even "public fields are evil" is "primarily opinion based" (not that I ever vote to close for that reason).

Comment: Basically, just about everything in programming, including public fields, has it legitimate uses.  Private methods, in particular, are an ideal way to encapsulate complex logic and/or avoid code duplication.  But of course, any concept can be used to excess, and it's the excess that's the problem, not the concept.

Comment: This (might) belong on Programmers SE. I voted to close because there's really nothing to this question -but- opinion (I disagree with the assertion that they're bad in any way, by the way).

Comment: @Kent - You're saying that the JDK source is the epitome of good programming??

Comment: What's wrong with private methods?  If it helps with readability and maintainability then go for them.  Refactoring a long method into lots of small, private, methods also helps the JITer.

Comment: You managed to phrase some objective questions, but the problem here is that any reasonable answer needs to address the issue why private methods may are or aren't bad. That inevitable leads to opinion based answers.

Comment: I read a lot of source code of library which come as part of JDK. And I see a lot private methods being used.Personally I think private method are great for factoring out your code. There is nothing wrong in their usage.
When ever you have a big logic, split them into as many small units as possible. That makes the code more readable.

I agree that it makes them look like C code with external field and many methods acting on them.But as far as you have foctored them properly.

Comment: @HotLicks your point is?

Comment: @kapep Addressing issues does not inevitably lead to opinion based answers.

Comment: @DavidSainty Right, but in this case the premise is 'private methods are bad', which leads to opinion based answers. With such a premise it doesn't really matter how objective the actual question is if it can't be reasonable answered without a discussion first.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Are there any standard Java guidelines limiting the use of private
>   methods?

No.

On the contrary - what can be `private` should be `private`. A lot of `private` methods in a class are in no way a bad practice (as long as the class itself is not too long). The interface should only offer the methods usable by outer classes. What happens inside, privately, is no one's bussiness.

It is actually much better to have one short `public` method and a few private ones (even if they are not called repeatedly), because it increases readability and makes a high-level overview over the one public method possible. If you have a `public` method which can be divided into multiple self-standing parts and you can name the parts, then do it. With a private method.

Comment: OK, that makes a lot of sense.  So there's no escaping the procedural paradigm *within* a class.

Comment: I think so, yes. You could make a class of a class of a class to abstract this all away, but that's just taking TNT to kill a mouse.

Comment: @Donkey_2009 if by procedural, you mean stuff gets done by following a procedure, i.e. `method1` calls `method2` then `method3`, yeah that's still essentially the plan. The difference between a procedural language and a OO language is mainly the data is separate from the functions in a procedural language.

Comment: What makes sense, when you have _lots_ of private methods, is to group some of them together within an another (inner?) class. But that's more because we don't want long classes than because we don't like many private methods.

Comment: If you are trying to followed SOLID coding. Then yes, they are code smell. As they violate SRP, and open/close.

Answer (score 3):

In general I do not consider the private methods as design flaws in code. When one should do a lot of calculations and they are forced to write compicated long methods, they can split it into smaller (private) methods. The benefit is wider if the private methods are to be used in many parts (methods) of a class. It is not elegant and not recommended to repeat the same code.

Comment: I'm not suggesting that you should ever repeat the same code.  But this is a design principle carried over from procedural languages such as C.  There are other ways to avoid code duplication which seem more object-oriented in style than using private methods, which seems too procedural.  For example, one could try and abstract away the private methods into a new class and call them from there.

Comment: @Donkey_2009 there's still an object, so what is procedural about it?

Comment: @Donkey_2009 - Creating a new object just to avoid a private class is pretty lame -- you're adding overhead AND reducing encapsulation.

Comment: So you agree on extracting smaller "helper" methods. But why would you put them somewhere else where they dont even belong? Consider the High Cohesion / Low Coupling principle (GRASP).

Answer (score 3):

> Are private methods as bad as public fields?

There is no question of good and bad. It is strictly based on your project design requirement. **Period.**

If you want any function that are only to be used by the defining class and should not be exposed to other classes you simply define it as private. From another perspective why would you expose a method that makes no sense outside the class by making it public.

Comment: Actually, the main reason for making it private is so you don't have to document it.

Comment: "you simply define it as private" - and to do otherwise is bad! **Period.**

Comment: @HotLicks you don't have to document it because user/client don't need to know it(as it has no use outside the class).

Comment: @AniketThakur - How long have you worked in the industry?

Comment: @HotLicks yeah I just graduated. It's just my opinion that documentation for private methods should only be for programmers and not in the documentation sent to the users(as it will unnecessarily confuse them). Correct me if my thinking is not right :)

Comment: My point (only slightly in jest) was that writing "official" documentation is a pain, so programmers will often make the decision to keep a method private purely to save the effort of documenting it, even when the method might be worthwhile as a public interface.  (OTOH, in some cases the programmer will err in the other direction to avoid needing to come back and make the method public later, when it turns out to be needed elsewhere.  Not every programming decision is based on high-sounding principles.)

Comment: If you have a private method in your class, and you want to follow solid. Simply abstract the private method out onto an interface, and DI it in.

Answer (score 1):

No. `private` methods are not bad design in anyway. They are good design, for the same reason as you don't want `public` fields. And that reason is encapsulation.

`private` methods enable encapsulation by protecting your code from being invoked from outside of the class. This restriction allows you to guarantee the state of your object.

The use of `private` methods does not make it like a procedural language. To achieve the effect of a procedural language in an OO language, one would have `static` methods operating on `static` fields.

```
public static CUnitEquivilent // Don't do this!
{
   private static int SomeVariableDefinedInCFile;

   public static int SomeVariableDefinedInHeader;

   private static SomeMethodDefinedInCFile(...){...}

   public static SomeMethodDefinedInHeader(...){...}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No, why should they be bad ? They are encouraged, since you have the ability to split your `public` methods, and not to have a method of 200 lines or more, and to reuse the same batch of code in your `class`.

One drawback is that you cannot *test* your `private` methods, but actually you shouldn't. Because they are not meant to be tested. (`public` method are meant to be tested.)